# Load a web page, execute its JavaScript and dump resulting HTML to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

I need to load a web page, execute its JavaScript (and all js files included with the  tags) and dump resulting HTLM to a file. This needs to be done on the server. I have tried node.js with zombie.js but it seems it is too immature to work in the real world. More often than not it just throws a bogus exception while a real browser (FireFox) has no issues with the page.

My node.js code is:

```
var zombie = require("zombie"),
    sys = require('sys');

// Load the page
var browser = new zombie.Browser({ debug: false });
browser.visit('http://www.dba.dk', function (error, browser, status) {
    if (error) { console.log('Error:' + error.message); }
    if (!error && browser.statusCode == 200) {
        sys.puts(browser.html);
    }
});
```

and it exits with an exception "TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of null"

Jaxer is not really an option.. I need to download a 3rd party page and execute it on my server. How would I do that with Jaxer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps that’s because you are using `err.message` whereas `err` is not defined?  `error`, on the other hand, *is* defined.

---

**Update**

Did you check out [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/)?

Also, it looks like [Aptana Jaxer](http://jaxer.org/) could do what you want.  To quote [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/server-side-javascript-with-jaxer/):

> Imagine ripping off the visual
>   rendering part of Firefox and
>   replacing it with a hook to Apache
>   instead - roughly speaking that's what
>   Jaxer is.

Comment: If that line of code was causing the error err would have to be null which it can't be, because null evaluates to false. However, it would mean that the real error message is not logged to the console.

Comment: @OscarKilhed: good point!  So that can’t be the actual cause of the error.  Still, the code as posted is not correct.

Comment: @Martijn: My fault, I have corrected the code. However this mistake has no effect on the actual error. Are there any other tools serving a similar purpose? I tried to use jsdom but couldn't find a way to execute page's javascript.

Comment: @andrew: I’ve added a few suggestions to my answer

Comment: @Martijn: Checking out PhantomJS. Looks promising. I will let you know about results later today

Comment: @Martijn: It seems PhantomJS can do what I need. However when I dump the HTML to a file it seems the dynamic content is NOT saved. I.e. external javascript files that modify DOM tree are not executed or at least I do not see changes to the tree. I use document.documentElement.innerHTML to dump the HTML

Comment: @intellion: Perhaps it’s best it you posted a separate question, specifically about PhantomJS.  You might get answers from people who have more experience with it.

Comment: @Martijn: Good advice! I'm so buried into this I didn't think about it