# How to download a web page with javascript executed?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load a web page, execute its JavaScript and dump resulting HTML to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392532/load-a-web-page-execute-its-javascript-and-dump-resulting-html-to-a-file)

i want to download html web pages like this one: http://www.google.com/insights/search/#q=iphone%204s&geo=GB&cmpt=q.

I actually can download them but the file doesn't have all the page's informations like graphic's value, categories, ...

I'd like to download them with all this informations, but these informations are avaible only if some javascript scripts are executed.

Someone can help me? I code in java so the answer should be in java or some web method.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/) is what you would be looking for.  The use of ScriptEngineManager to interpret the javascript.  Running the required javascript functions with the necessary variables through this should output what you are looking for.  More information on the class is available here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html